# Phonegap Windows Phoneg Get Started

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-phone

I downloaded visual studio professional 2010 and visual studio service pack 1 and windows phone sdk 7 and phonegap 2.9.0.

I m following this tutorial http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html to create a windows phone project in visual studio.

in my C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C# i copied the CordovaWP7_2_9_0 that i found in C:\Users\User\Desktop\phonegap-2.9.0\lib\windows-phone-7 , i open the visual studio and i click file -> New Project -> Visual C# i can find CordovaWP7_2_9_0 . when i click on OK , it generates a project but there is no WWW Folder or index.html . here is image of want i see http://postimg.org/image/5yw8yyzr7/. It's not the same of what i see in the tutorial.
Please Help . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That article is **REALLY** outdated.

I'd recommend using the new approach, which is Visual Studio 2013 and the [Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675).